# Magento 2 - How to get the simple product Sku from the option selected of a configurable product

Tags: magento2.2, configurable-product

As I asked in the question I want to get the SKU of a simple product selected by the option in configurable product details page.

How can I capture the SKU?

Tried in this way, but not possible to capture the selected options SKU

```
$product_id =  $block->getProduct()->getId();//Configurable product ID

$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

foreach ($_children as $child){
    echo "Here are your child Product Ids ".$child->getID()."-:-".$child->getSku()."</br>";
}
echo "count: ".count($_children);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i am not getting any error, i cannot capture the selected option sku.

Comment: Where did you write this code? I think you want the selected option's sku when customer select any options right?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, yes exactly. i wrote this on product details page related phtml file

Comment: You need to manage it through ajax call when option is selected. Are you using swatch or dropdown?

Comment: i am using Drop-down.i updated the question with a image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82527/discussion-between-mujahidh-and-sukumar-gorai).

Answer (score 2):

This the script you need to add on your phtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
                selectedProduct();
            });
        });

        function selectedProduct() {
            var selected_options = {};
            jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
                var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('attribute-id');
                var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('option-selected');
                if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
                selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
            });

            var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
            var found_ids = [];
            jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
                var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
                    return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
                }
                if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
                    console.log(product_id);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('getsku'); ?>",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {id:product_id},
                        showLoader: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                } 
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Create a module with name Vendor_Module.

Also you need to create a routes.xml for frontend like below:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

and add the following code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="getsku" id="getsku">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now create one controller to below path:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        echo $this->_productRepository->getById($id)->getSku();        
    }

}
```

You will get the sku in your ajax response. You can now do whatever you want with the sku.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank u so much you saved my time

Comment: Welcome! Happy Coding!

Comment: can you please help me,  how to get a  selected option id (or)  attribute id  in product detail page

Comment: I am getting error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
".  on line "var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;"

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change. **But not SKU.**More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to get the **SKU** of the selected product on frontend, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **SKU** for each simple product.

Switching **SKU** when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements) (*Visual Swatch*, *Text Swatch*, *Dropdown*).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.