# How to getSku for configurable products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, attribute-options

I want to get Sku for selected options.

[image]

Above image i have select blue and M. So this options product sku get in magento 2.

Please Help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: check this answer, it may be helpful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240405/84221

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get the sku of any product:

$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

foreach ($_children as $child){

echo "Here are your child Product Ids ".$child->getID()."\n";

}

echo "count: ".count($_children);

But if you want to see the configurable product sku in frontend

Visit https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-get-simple-products-of-configurable-product-in-magento-2.html