# Get SKU of simple product after selecting options of configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, sku

How can I get the SKU of a simple product on a configurable product, after options are selected?

I tried this solution but I get various errors and issues which make me think it is outdated.
[Magento 2 - How to get the simple product Sku from the option selected of a configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240353/magento-2-how-to-get-the-simple-product-sku-from-the-option-selected-of-a-conf#comment476946_240405)

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **SKU** for each simple product. Out of the box, when choosing options, *images*, *price*, etc will change, but **not SKU.**

The **SKU** obtained with `getJsonConfig()` can be updated in the frontend when selecting an option in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` or/and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements) (*Dropdown*, *Visual Swatch*, *Text Swatch*).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.